# Creating xml from ListView items

Tags: android, listview, xml-parsing

i have a list view that is being populated from Database user can edit item at run time and then save them. what i want is to get all  items of ListView parsed in a xml file and save that xml on sdCard.

Here is my ListView being populated from  ArrayList ..

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, sData));
```

Comment: ...and when you update the listview, your xml should also be updated ? Right ??

Comment: You can create a file and write to it with standard Java libraries. Just read values from the cursor and write them to the file.

Comment: @Karakuri : It worked :-) had to made some other modifications in code as well but its working :-)